# How to send command from bot to discrord chanel

Tags: python, discord

For example channel have /some_command[prompt]

How to call with command and prompt instead text ?

```
async def on_ready():
   await client.wait_until_ready()
   channel = client.get_channel(int(chanel_id))
   await channel.send("/some_command[test]")
```

Answer (score 0):

So replace:

```
await channel.send("/some_command[test]")
```

with

```
await channel.send("</commandname:commandid>")
```

And you should get what you are looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: same result as before